# Use passport.js for register users or manually create them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, bookshelf.js

Looking at internet a lot of people is doing the "Signup" methods within Passport, using local strategies. But, has this any advantage between creating the record in the database manually?

I want to mean, if we use a strategy of passport for doing this, we can do:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({
      email: email
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        return done(null, false);
      } else {
        User.create(req.body)
        .then(userCreated => {
          return done(null, userCreated);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return done(err)
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return done(err)
    });
  }
));
```

But is this actually needed? Or can we create our user as this? (using Bookshelf.js):

```
 this.model.findOne({
   email: email
 })
 .then(user => {
   if (user) {
     res.status(403).json({
       message: 'Email not available.'
     });
   } else {
     User.create(req.body)
     .then(userCreated => {
       res.status(201).json(userCreated);
     })
     .catch(err => {
       next(err);
     });
   }
 })
 .catch(err => {
   next(err);
 });
}
```

Comment: Usually passportjs is used for authentication purposes, if you want to go further and create a user if he's not registered, it's up to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's define clearly what is Passport.js:

> "Passport is authentication middleware for Node" (http://www.passportjs.org/docs/)

You shure can create the user like that and then handle the rest of the login process with your on code.

But when your authentication rules become more complex (and they will) that's when Passport.js becomes handy.

Using it, you don't need to waste your time creating the code to handle access restriction, API exposures, etc. Passports.js handles all of this for you. Hence, you can focus on other implementation details of your application.